# why the x-axis longitude value in exponent value instead of decimal degree? I'm using pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import csv

dataset = pd.read_csv('bbkp1.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:,[2,1]].values


from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
wcss = []

for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=300,n_init=10, random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)

plt.plot(range(1,11), wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method Graph')
plt.xlabel('Number of Clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5,init='k-means++',max_iter=300,n_init=10,random_state=0)
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
x_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(X)

centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_

plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans==0,0],X[y_kmeans==0,1],s=20,c='red',label='Cluster 1')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans==1,0],X[y_kmeans==1,1],s=20,c='blue',label='Cluster 2')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans==2,0],X[y_kmeans==2,1],s=20,c='green',label='Cluster 3')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans==3,0],X[y_kmeans==3,1],s=20,c='cyan',label='Cluster 4')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans==4,0],X[y_kmeans==4,1],s=20,c='magenta',label='Cluster 5')

plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,1], s=70, c='yellow', label='Centroids')
plt.title('Clusters of Bandar Baru Kangkar Pulai')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

the coordinate latitude 1.5xx and longitude 103.xx of my dataset. But when I run the code, the graph show x-axis values in exponent values instead of 103.xxx. here is the result of the graph I got:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's showing values in that way,
but you can manually format the ticker string using `matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter`.
Here is the [link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter) to the documentation.

```py
import csv

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

sns.set()

dataset = pd.read_csv('bbkp1.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, [2,1]].values

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5,init='k-means++',max_iter=300,n_init=10,random_state=0)
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
x_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(X)

centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(X[y_kmeans==0,0],X[y_kmeans==0,1],s=20,c='red',label='Cluster 1')
ax.scatter(X[y_kmeans==1,0],X[y_kmeans==1,1],s=20,c='blue',label='Cluster 2')
ax.scatter(X[y_kmeans==2,0],X[y_kmeans==2,1],s=20,c='green',label='Cluster 3')
ax.scatter(X[y_kmeans==3,0],X[y_kmeans==3,1],s=20,c='cyan',label='Cluster 4')
ax.scatter(X[y_kmeans==4,0],X[y_kmeans==4,1],s=20,c='magenta',label='Cluster 5')

ax.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,1], s=70, c='yellow', label='Centroids')

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.3f'))  # 3 decimal places

plt.title('Clusters of Bandar Baru Kangkar Pulai')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I already try matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter. then i get an error. fig, ax = plt.subplot()
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AxesSubplot object

Comment: It's `subplots()` with `s` at the end. These are two different methods.